# flutter-keyboard hides itself when clicked on textfield

Tags: forms, flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

```
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager(12513): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 12513 view : com.example.facatte
D/InputMethodManager(12513): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f0b7259[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(12513): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(12513): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f0b7259[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(12513): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(12513): Starting input: tba=com.example.facatte ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@8b758fe mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(12513): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(12513): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(12513): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=93
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12513): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12513): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2340) ci=(0,83,0,989) vi=(0,83,0,989) or=1
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=12 res=0x1 s={true 518951051264} ch=false
D/InputMethodManager(12513): HSIFW - flag : 0
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2340) ci=(0,83,0,126) vi=(0,83,0,126) or=1
I/ViewRootImpl@799941b[MainActivity](12513): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=12 res=0x1 s={true 518951051264} ch=false
```

This is the output in console when tapping on the textfield.
The keyboard comes up for 2 seconds and then hides automatically. It doesnt throw any error too !

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();


return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body : Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: TextField(
    controller: textEditingController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Type Your Data',
    ),
  ),
));
```

Or If you are using Multiple TextFields then use a separate controller for each TextField. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: declaring the formkey as static i.e , static GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>(); Solved the problem.Thanks. Reference -https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20042